# How can the value get updated in update_attribute

Tags: ruby-on-rails, update-attribute

I have a test, that needs to set up some database-state:

```
before do
  Site.first.update_attribute(:primary_domain, @params[:order][:primary_domain])
end
```

But, for some reason, this modifies the @params:

```
before do
  @params[:order][:primary_domain].must_equal "example.com"
  Site.first.update_attribute(:primary_domain, @params[:order][:primary_domain])
  @params[:order][:primary_domain].must_equal "example.com"
end
```

This fails, the second `@params[:order][:primary_domain].must_equal "example.com"` fails, something updates the `@params[:order][:primary_domain]` there. Weird, I would have expected `update_attribute(name, value)` to not touch the `value`, but somehow, it does.

It can be circumvented with a `.dup`. But I am interested as to what could cause this. Is it maybe a scope issue? Something to do with the fact that I am normalising the `Site.primary_domain` on `save`, maybe?

```
# Override the primary_domain setter.
# Allows us to normalise the domain
def primary_domain=(primary_domain)
  return primary_domain unless primary_domain.is_a?(String)
  write_attribute(:primary_domain, Site.parse_uri(primary_domain.dup).host)
end
```

Comment: That's impossible. From the code nobody touched that hash. Please paste full error. If it's not equal, there is normally an actual value, what's that?

Comment: There is no error. And I read the code for `update_attribute()`  which left me flabbergasted and is the reason for posting this Q. Since there is no error, any other details that I could post here to help you further?

Comment: I think the real failure would be update_attribute. Not sure you are using Rails 3 or 4, if 3, there may be attr_accessible error. You can check log/test.log to see the details. Or run the test with backtrace parameter to see the backtrace.